# BackboneJS and Rails 3 - Sync problems with $.ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, backbone.js

I'm having trouble getting BackboneJS's syncing to work with my rails3 backend. I'm trying to use the JSON posts, and it sends my data in {_json: {}}. The problem with this is that the authenticity_token is then not included. (Or perhaps it is, but in the _json parameter).  Rails won't deserialize it, even though I've forced the ajax options:
{contentType: 'application/json', dataType: "json"}.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this adapter that incorporates Rails' authenticity token:

https://github.com/Maciek416/BackboneRailsAuthTokenAdapter

Source: Ed Schmalzle on the [Philly.rb mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/phillyrb/browse_thread/thread/bb3b022638484690)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a before_filter that pulls the token out of request.parameters and sets it in the params hash?